# How to use a custom structure in place of KeyValuePair?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible to use a custom structure in place of a KeyValuePair?

Instead of

```
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of class1,class2) In myDict
  Dim c1 As kvp.Key
  Dim c2 As kvp.Value
Next
```

I'd like to use

```
For Each kvp As myKvp In myDict
  Dim c1 As kvp.P1
  Dim c2 As kvp.P2
Next
```

I want to use myKvp in place of KeyValuePair(Of class1,class2) only (not for other types).

I tried creating myKvp as

```
Public Structure myKvp    

  Public P1 As class1
  Public P2 As class2

  Public Sub New(_p1 As class1,_p2 As class2)
    P1 = _p1
    P2 = _p2
  End Sub

End Structure
```

but I get the message

Value of type `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of ASP...class1, ASP...class2)` cannot be converted to 'ASP...myKvp'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly create an instance of `myKvp`. You can do it easily with Linq:

```
For Each kvp As myKvp In myDict.Select(Function(x) New myKvp(x.Key, x.Value))
  Dim c1 = kvp.P1
  Dim c2 = kvp.P2
Next
```

Comment: It's good to know that this can be accomplished, but this really doesn't simplify things.  It's too much overhead to just get more meaningful names for the properties of the kvp.  I guess I'll just stick with .Key & .Value

Comment: @ic3b3rg, you can always use an anonymous type instead of creating your own KVP struct: `myDict.Select(Function(x) New With { .P1 = x.Key, .P2 = x.Value })`

Comment: I'll definitely file that away for future use.  In this case I think I'm better off just living with the default properties.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a dictionary use a List or any other generic collection. Dictionaries require KeyValuePair as their collection items.

Update:

You could create your own class that subclasses the actual `Dictionary<T,S>` object and expose public properties whose names are more meaningful than `Key` and `Value` but are just pointers to the underlying `Dictionary`'s `Key` and `Value`. You would still retain all the functionality of the underlying Dictionary.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I agree, use `Dim myDict As New List(Of myKvP)`

Comment: It's good advice and I considered switching to a List.  Unfortunately, I also need to search by key and I don't want an O(n) operation for that.  It looks like I'll just stick with the Dictionary and KeyValuePair.

Answer (score 0):

The short-and-pedantic answer is, no.

While the two structures have the same layout, the compiler will interpret the act of defining myKvp (instead of using the generic KeyValuePair) as you actively stating that you want it to treat them as two distinct things.  After all, if KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue) is what you wanted then why not just use KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)?

However, you can sneak around it by [implementing CType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf7b9sy7.aspx) for your custom type.  But doing that won't be quite the same as telling the compiler to treat myKvp as an alias for KeyValuePair(of Class1, Class2) - instead, it's telling the compiler that, when needed, you can take all the data out of an instance of one class, and shoehorn it into a new instance of the other by using the CType() function that you've supplied.